# hyperref form: how to change labels and fields appearance

Tags: tables, formatting, hyperref, forms

I want to create a PDF fillable form, so I came up with a LaTeX+`hyperref hypothesis`. My form's style should be similar to the one of DnD 3.5 PCs sheets:

[image]

In particular, what I want to reproduce is the table-like look with labels written in white over a black background and positioned near or above their fields. I also need the more "discreet" ones below AC values. Is that possible?

What I suppose I can do is either:

1. put the fields in a customised table, or
2. restyle the labels and fields style and borders.

But both of the solutions look a bit too "technical" for me. If they are realizable, may someone provide a tutorial? Otherwise, is there another solution? At the moment I don't even have a draft, so any option is acceptable.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{a header text} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\TextField[name=example, width={5cm}]{}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` could serve as a starting point.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, I tried it and seems I can play with it to get what I need. Just a note if someone tries the code - `\TextField` must be used in a `Form` environment.